# WPF/XAML ProgressBar is not showing 100% width

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, width

I have a question about the XAML code of the ProgressBar. I have the following XAML code to display the Bar:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="80" Style="{StaticResource Progress}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
```

The control to display the bar is:

```
 <!-- Progress bar control -->
    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar" x:Key="Progress">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource colorProgressbackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource colorProgressactivity}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource colorProgressbackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid Name="TemplateRoot"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                           RadiusX="4"
                           RadiusY="4"  />
                        <Border Background="{StaticResource colorProgressbackground}"
                        Margin="1"
                        CornerRadius="2" />
                        <Decorator Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Grid Name="Foreground">
                                <Grid Name="Animation" ClipToBounds="True">
                                    <Border Name="PART_GlowRect" Width="{TemplateBinding Value}" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="4" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{StaticResource colorProgressactivity}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Decorator>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now, the problem is that the bar is 100% width, but the active bar (the Value-variable in the ProgressBar code) is not 80 percent, but 80 pixels (or so). I cannot give the Gray bar a hardcoded width. How can I make sure that the active bar (PART_indicator) is showing up correctly in percentages?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't don't this in a while now but if you set min as 0 and max as 100 .. value = 80 should take you to 80% really .. lemme try !

Comment: just tried making a progressbar like this .....  <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="80" Width="500" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25"/>

.. it looks roughly 80% filled in for the wholebar

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for the control, it looks like it handles setting the 'Part_Indicator' width automatically.

From reflector

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    if (this._track != null)
    {
        this._track.SizeChanged -= new SizeChangedEventHandler(this.OnTrackSizeChanged);
    }
    this._track = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_Track") as FrameworkElement;
    this._indicator = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_Indicator") as FrameworkElement;
    this._glow = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_GlowRect") as FrameworkElement;
    if (this._track != null)
    {
        this._track.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(this.OnTrackSizeChanged);
    }
    if (this.IsIndeterminate)
    {
        this.SetProgressBarGlowElementBrush();
    }
}
```

..

```
private void SetProgressBarIndicatorLength()
{
    if ((this._track != null) && (this._indicator != null))
    {
        double minimum = base.Minimum;
        double maximum = base.Maximum;
        double num3 = base.Value;
        double num4 = (this.IsIndeterminate || (maximum <= minimum)) ? 1.0 : ((num3 - minimum) / (maximum - minimum));
        this._indicator.Width = num4 * this._track.ActualWidth;
        this.UpdateAnimation();
    }
}
```

[This custom template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750638(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't seem to have to take the % into account, are you sure that the `Part_Indicator` is not correctly sizing but you are then sizing the `Part_GlowRect` incorrectly based on the Value ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'll try this code and I think it's a great solution. But, I keep thinking there should be a solution without involving any code-behind, just because as @Muds mentoined, the default behavior is respecting percentages.

Comment: This is not code for you to try - its code from reflector that shows how the control works internally - what I am saying is that it is taken care of for you and it will size your Part_Indicator automatically